# Google-Fit Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER equivalent in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, google-fit

Given the following code in Android

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager)        
        getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
private Sensor     mStepCounterSensor = mSensorManager
        .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
private Sensor       mStepDetectorSensor = mSensorManager
        .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR);
```

I cannot figure out the relative Xamarin.Android Code. 
Particularly I cannot find the equivalent of `Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER` and `Sensor.TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR`.

Trying with `Sensor.StringTypeStepCounter` and `Sensor.StringTypeStepDetector` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit I found it out:

```
private SensorManager mSensorManager = (SensorManager) GetSystemService(Context.SensorService);

private Sensor mStepCounterSensor = mSensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.StepCounter);

private Sensor mStepDetectorSensor = mSensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.StepDetector);
```